# Verifying desirable properties for cost functions for mean square error.

Tags: probability, statistics, mean-square-error

In my Machine Learning course I was told that some desirable properties for cost functions are:

> When the target y is real-valued, it is desirable that the cost is
>   symmetric around 0, since both positive and negative errors should be
>   penalized equally.
>
> Also, our cost function should penalize “large” mistakes and
>   “very large” mistakes similarly.

Then we define mean squared error as:

$MSE(w) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}[y_n - f(x_n)]^2$

My question is how would I verify the above properties mathematically? Are these properties verified no matter what the model $f$ is taken to be (in class we just saw linear regression)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error at a given point is, by definition, the value $y_n - f(x_n)$.

Let $e_n = y_n - f(x_n)$ be the error for point $n$. If you want to penalize as much negative errors than positive ones, it means that replacing $e_n$ by $-e_n$ will not change anything in the computation of your global cost. You can verify that it is the case.

Now, you can also remark that "large" $e_n$ will be more important in your cost function that "small" $e_n$ because of the square, however "very large" errors will be even more important than "large" errors -- I think your teacher intended the former.

In these two paragraphs, I made no assumptions about $f$, so the conclusions are independant of $f$.